# AVSpeechSynthesizer ignoring mute switch on iOS 13

Tags: avaudiosession, avspeechsynthesizer, ios13

Any AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance on iOS 13 ignores the mute/silent switch and plays the audio through the device's speakers. I thought maybe I had some weird audio setting in my app that was causing this, but I just tried creating a demo app that does nothing but play an AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance and it ignores the mute switch as well. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

EDIT: This was fixed in beta 5.

Comment: Oh hey CARROT! Didn't expect to see you here!